# Why would you prefer Java 8 Stream API instead of direct hibernate/sql queries when working with the DB

Tags: java, hibernate, java-8, java-stream

Recently I see a lot of code in few projects using stream for filtering objects, like:

```
library.stream()
          .map(book -> book.getAuthor())
          .filter(author -> author.getAge() >= 50)
          .map(Author::getSurname)
          .map(String::toUpperCase)
          .distinct()
          .limit(15)
          .collect(toList()));
```

Is there any advantages of using that instead of direct HQL/SQL query to the database returning already the filtered results.

Isn't the second aproach much faster?

Comment: One is maintainability. While HQL/SQL queries may often be faster, typos in these queries may only be caught at runtime. E.g. `author.getAge() > t0` will most likely be flagged by the compiler, this typo could slip into production when using a query (`AGE > t0`). 

Also, some people may be familiar with the methods above and can use them to build complicated things. If things change, it's easy to rewrite in place. Building an equivalent query may be hard, esp. without SQL experience.

One additional thing: what if everything's in memory anyway?

Comment: actually it depends there are libraries that use Java8 streams and convert that in the end to SQL. So without knowing which libraries are in use it is actually hard to tell.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If the data originally comes from a DB it is better to do the filtering in the DB rather than fetching everything and filtering locally.

First, Database management systems are good at filtering, it is part of their main job and they are therefore optimized for it. The filtering can also be sped up by using indexes.

Second, fetching and transmitting many records and to unmarshal the data into objects just to throw away a lot of them when doing local filtering is a waste of bandwidth and computing resources.

Comment: @Eugene, because `fetchAll, filter later` operation implies a waste of system resources for each entity that got discarded by `filter` operation, since we actually forced database and our mapping framework to do more work than is necessary for our needs. This should be explained in the answer though.

Comment: @Eugene, agree with you completely, this answer should be expanded with more explanation.

Answer (score 25):

On a first glance: streams can be made to run in parallel; **just** by changing code to use `parallelStream()`. (disclaimer: of course it depends on the specific context if just changing the stream type will result in correct results; but yes, it *can* be that easy).

Then: streams "invite" to use lambda expressions. And those in turn lead to usage of [invoke_dynamic](https://www.infoq.com/articles/Invokedynamic-Javas-secret-weapon) bytecode instructions; sometimes gaining performance advantages compared to  "old-school" kind of writing such code. (and to clarify the misunderstanding: invoke_dynamic is a property of lambdas, not streams!)

These would be reasons to prefer "stream" solutions nowadays (from a general point of view).

Beyond that: it really depends ... lets have a look at your example input. This looks like dealing with ordinary Java POJOs, that already reside in memory, within some sort of collection. Processing such objects **in memory** directly would definitely be faster than going to some off-process database to do work there!

But, of course: when the above calls, like `book.getAuthor()` would be doing a "deep dive" and actually talk to an underlying database; then chances are that "doing the whole thing in a single query" gives you better performance.

Comment: One interesting possibility is that the call chain above is actually a fluent builder that lazily constructs a query, IOW it could be that it is actually #1 *and* #2: using the stream API, but doing everything in the DB. You can't tell from the snippet in the question without knowing the implementations of those methods.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, that said, a query builder would work in, for example, .NET with Linq, but not in Java: there is no way in plain java to tell what a lambda does, especially the part with `author.getAge() > 50`, where no query builder can examine and gain access to `> 50` part - that is available only at compile time, basically, where query builder sees the uninterpreted Java text. Interpretable query would've been possible if that line looked like `author.getAge().greaterThan(50)` or something.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov: You're right. I always forget that operators are broken in Java. It would theoretically be possible to parse bytecode or something like that, but that would leave the realm of Java, and would e.g. break on implementations of Java that don't use JVM bytecode (like Android, for example).

Comment: @JörgWMittag, I wouldn't say they are broken per se - Java just doesn't allow you to override them, which can be seen as a good thing as well (because it relieves you of the mental excercise of guessing what will that operator do when executed and whether or not it was overridden at any point, will it do side effects and what perf it has for any given input).

Comment: @M.Prokhorov: I never got that argument. An operator is just a method with a funny name. Everything you say applies to methods, too. So, either a) you forbid people make up their own names for methods, overloading methods, and overriding methods as well as operators, or b) you allow people to make up their own operators, overload operators, and override operators. Allowing it for methods but forbidding it for operators makes no sense, since they are both basically the same. Either you allow it for both or you forbid it for both; both are valid choices. But this strange in between thing just …

Comment: … doesn't make sense. But that's a rant for another day. Java *does* allow you to overload a method named `plus`, but it doesn't allow you to overload a method named `+`. But, `+` *is* overloaded, so why is overloading it confusing when it is done by you, but not confusing when it is done by Oracle?

Comment: @JörgWMittag, well, operators aren't truly methods because they have a notion of precedence which methods don't - at least in Java. There are languages which did away with operator precedence to reinforce that "operator is a method with funny name", and that move in my eyes (and many others') violated principle of least astonishment. We are unlikely to reach definite agreement of this, So yes, that would be a matter to discuss at another time.

Comment: @Eugene You are correct; I updated my answer to make clear that invokedynamic is about lambdas; not streams.

Comment: @JörgWMittag But remember that some libraries *do* do weird stuff involving parsing bytecode. It's not impossible or even implausible.

Answer (score 13):

The first thing is to realize, that you can't tell from just this code, what statement is issued against the database. It might very well, that all the filtering, limiting and mapping is collected, and upon the invocation of `collect` all that information is used to construct a matching SQL statement (or whatever query language is used) and send to the database.

With this in mind there are many reasons why streamlike APIs are used.

1. It is hip. Streams and lambdas are still rather new to most java developers, so they feel cool when they use it.
2. If something like in the first paragraph is used it actually creates a nice DSL to construct your query statements. [Scalas Slick](http://slick.lightbend.com/) and [.Net LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx) where early examples I know about, although I assume somebody build something like it in LISP long before I was born.
3. The streams might be [reactive streams](http://www.reactive-streams.org/) and encapsulate a non-blocking API. While these APIs are really nice because they don't force you to block resources like threads while you are waiting for results. Using them requires either tons of callbacks or using a much nicer stream based API to process the results.
4. They are nicer to read the imperative code. Maybe the processing done in the stream can't [easily/by the author] be done with SQL. So the alternatives aren't SQL vs Java (or what ever language you are using), but imperative Java or "functional" Java. The later often reads nicer.

So there are good reasons to use such an API.

With all that said: It is, in almost all cases, a bad idea to do any sorting/filtering and the like in your application, when you can offload it to the database. The only exception I can currently think of is when you can skip the whole roundtrip to the database, because you already have the result locally (e.g. in a cache).

Answer (score 8):

Well, your question should ideally be - **Is it better to do reduction / filtering operations in the DB or fetch all records and do it in Java using Streams?**

The answer isn't straightforward and any stats that give a "concrete" answer will not generalize to all cases.

The operations you are talking about **are better done in the DB itself, because that is what DBs are designed for, very fast handling of data**. Of course usually in case of relational databases, there will be some "book-keeping and locks" being used to ensure that independent transactions don't end up making the data inconsistent, but even with that, DBs do a pretty good job in filtering data, especially large data sets.

One case where I would prefer filtering data in Java code rather than in DB would be if you need to filter different features from the same data. For example, right now you are getting only the Author's surname. If you wanted to get all books written by the author, ages of authors, children of author, place of birth etc. Then it makes sense to get only one "read-only" copy from the DB and use parallel streams to get different information from the same data set.

Answer (score 5):

Unless measured and *proven* for a *specific scenario* either could be good or equally bad. The reason you **usually** want to take these kind of queries to the database is because (among other things):

> DB can handle much larger data then your java process
>
> Queries in a database can be indexed (making them much faster)

On the other hand, if your data is small, using a `Stream` the way you did is effective. Writing such a Stream pipeline is **very readable** (once you *talk* Streams good enough).

Comment: Note that some of my java processes are handling Gigabytes of data. Streams, when used correctly are exactly suitable to handle huge data volumes. The idea is to setup a pipeline that processes and write data as it comes in. And where you run aground in complexity, you can switch over to something like Apache Spark that evolves this idea further into RDD’s, not to mention how you can harness multiple servers as a single distributed computational engine ...

Answer (score 4):

Hibernate and other ORMs are usually way more useful for writing entities rather than reading, because they allow developers to offload ordering of specific writes to framework that almost never will "get that wrong".

Now, for reading and reporting, on the other hand (and considering we are talking DB here) an SQL query is likely to be better because there will not be any frameworks in-between, and you will be able to tune query performance in terms of database that will be invoking this query rather than in terms of your framework of choice, which gives more flexibility to how that tuning can be done, sort of.